# Ingresar un archivo .txt como entrada

Tags: c, archivo, formato, txt

intento leer un archivo .txt con el nombre ingresado por el usuario, con el .txt incluido, de manera de que si es el formato incorrecto se lo diga al usuario "Formato de archivo incorrecto" y volver a mostrar la opciones anteriores. Si el archivo no existe le dice al usuario "archivo no existente". Tampoco se me ocurre como hacer los if que mencione anteriormente.

El código me compila, por lo cual no encuentro la razón exacta del fallo, el programa se cierra al ejecutar. Gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int archivo_existe(char *nombreArchivo)
{
  struct stat (buffer);   
  return (stat (nombreArchivo, &buffer) == 0);
}

int main(){
    char *name, *extension;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    while(v1 == 0 && v2 == 0){
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del archivo matriz P: ");
        scanf("%s",&name);
        //while para ver si el archivo existe o no
        while(v1==0){
            if(archivo_existe(name)){
                v1 = 1;
            }
            else{
                printf("Archivo no existente\n");
            }
        }
        //while para ver si el formato es correcto o no
        while(v2 == 0){
            extension = strtok(name, ".");
            while(extension != NULL){
                extension = strtok(NULL, ".");
                if(extension == "txt"){
                    v2 = 1;
                }
                else{
                    printf("Formato de archivo incorrecto\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No precisas los bucle while interiores además lo tienes puesto que de todas formas si falla nunca sale del bucle, lo puedes hacer así:

```
int main()
{
    char *name, *extension;
    int v1 = 0;
    while(v1 == 0) {
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del archivo matriz P: ");
        scanf("%s",&name);
        // Miramos si el archivo existe entonces investigamos la extensión
        if (archivo_existe(name))
        {
            extension = strtok(name, ".");
            if (extension != NULL) {
                extension = strtok(NULL, ".");
                if(extension != "txt")
                   printf("Formato de archivo incorrecto\n");
                else
                   v1=1;  // Todo satisfactorio 
            }                  
        }    
        else {
            printf("Archivo no existente\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> el programa se cierra al ejecutar ...

Por la sencilla razón de que no has reservado memoria para almacenar la entrada del usuario:

```
char *name;
...
scanf("%s",&name);
```

Así estás almacenando la entrada en una posición incorrecta en la memoria; recordemos que C **no inicializa** las variables por nosotros, por lo que `name` contendrá un valor *indefinido*, normalmente aleatorio.

Basta con usar un *array* para solucionar esto:

```
char name[250];
...
scanf("%s",&name);
```

**Observa** que no tenemos en cuenta este límite de tamaño, por lo que si el usuario introduce mas de 249 caracteres, el resultado será ... *curioso*.

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar si un archivo existe, intenta abrirlo en modo lectura:

```
FILE *archivo = fopen(nombre, "r");
//          Modo lectura ---> ^^^
```

Si el archivo cuyo nombre está contenido en `nombre` no existe, el puntero `archivo` será `NULL`, por lo tanto:

> [...] si es el formato incorrecto se lo diga al usuario "Formato de archivo incorrecto" y volver a mostrar la opciones anteriores. Si el archivo no existe le dice al usuario "archivo no existente".

```
char *name;

/* Solo se sale del bucle cuando 'pedir_datos' es 0, que sucederá cuando
   el nombre del archivo acabe en ".txt" y el archivo exista. */
for (int pedir_datos = 1; pedir_datos; )
{
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del archivo matriz P: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    // Comprobamos la extensión, sabemos que son los 4 últimos caracteres:
    size_t longitud = strlen(name);
    pedir_datos = strcmp(".txt", name + longitud - 4)) ? 0u : 1u;

    if (!pedir_datos) // Solo se entra si el nombre acababa en ".txt"
    {
        FILE *archivo = fopen(name, "r");
        pedir_datos = archivo ? 0u : 1u;
        fclose(archivo);
    }
}
```